# Custom RatingBar styles only show one dot, other weird behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-styles, ratingbar

I have the following code set up to create a custom `RatingBar` style on Android:

In `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/rating_bar_height</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/rating_bar_height</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/circle_ratingbar_full</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In `res/drawable/circle_ratingbar_full.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/circle_ratingbar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

In `res/drawable/circle_ratingbar_full_empty.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />

</selector>
```

In `res/drawable/circle_ratingbar_full_filled.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />

</selector>
```

Furthermore, I have two images, `res/drawable/button_enabled.png` and `res/drawable/button_disabled.png` that I want to use to replace the stars on the `RatingBar`.

Android Studio seems to not have a problem with the individual drawables. However, when I use this style in a `RatingBar` in an xml layout, the `RatingBar`, which in its default style works without any problems, has a few problems:

1. Instead of a variable number of rating drawables, I see only one, regardless of the number of stars set.
2. If I don't set the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` in the style, the `RatingBar` will stretch to a larger height, but still only the one custom star (circle).
3. If put inside of a `ListView` item view, the item view itself is no longer clickable (item view is clickable with the default styles).

Is there something I'm missing in this setup? I resorted to copying the drawables straight from the default `RatingBar` styles in the SDK and swapping for my values (which results in the code above), and it still doesn't work.

Snippet of usage in layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/accessory_view">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_min_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Min Value"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_max_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Max Value"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        style="@style/MyRatingBar"
        android:stepSize="1.0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

After further testing, I have found that clicking on any given part of the single dot that I see will actually change the rating to a value matching *where* I clicked it. So it seems the RatingBar is acting like a ProgressBar with a 0.5 step. So instead of using the drawable once for each star it should have, it seems to be using the drawable *once* as the background of the whole RatingBar area.

Does anyone know how to make it so that I can simply replace the star drawables and retain all the other RatingBar behavior?

Comment: I've tried doing exactly what you are doing and it looks okay in my layout preview. Can you show how you're using it in the layout?

Comment: Updated to show usage

Comment: I made a test xml layout matching your snippet, still seems okay. Just to clarify, it's displaying incorrectly in your layout preview AND when you test, right?

Comment: That's correct. Also, I'm using the latest SDK and Android Studio 1.0.RC2.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. :\  I can't reproduce it in my environment.

Comment: That's at least something to go on. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I tried this out on a fresh project and it still does the same thing, and tried it on a coworker's computer with the same results.

Comment: Interesting. I'd be willing to try out your code on my machine if you're desperate for a solution, maybe I could locate the issue.

Comment: Sample app is here: https://github.com/shekibobo/custom-rating-bar-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened your test project and did some trial-and-error debugging. My conclusion is that you cannot use XML shape drawables as progressDrawables in a `RatingBar`. The Android platform `RatingBar` drawables are all `.png` files, which is a pretty good indicator that XML drawable are probably not supported. I tried using bitmap drawables in your test project and they worked fine.

You only solution seems to be to use bitmap drawables, unless you can figure out your own implementation of a RatingBar.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out that the `.png`s I was using were actually `.9.png`, which would give a clue as to why it didn't work. Apparently anything that could be stretchable can't be used as a replacement drawable.

Comment: Great, glad I could get you going in the right direction. As a bonus, I learned something new as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to fix this problem. You should go to your Gradle (module:app), and change the compatibility. Replace with this one:

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

And then, replace the ActionBarActivity extends of your MainActivity, because this class is deprecated. Now you must to use AppCompatActivity.

read more here: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LNyDnnBYJ8r